# Mapping response with Object Mapper

Tags: ios, swift

i am using https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper to map my response for api calls. I have written a generic method to handle all api call. Below is method

```
 func post<T: Mappable>(obj: T.Type, endPoint:String ,params:[String:Any], success : @escaping (T) -> Void, failure : @escaping (String) -> Void){
        Alamofire.request(baseUrl+endPoint,method: .post, parameters:params).responseObject { (response:DataResponse<BaseResponse<T>>) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let response):
                if let status = response.status,  status.isSuccess {
                    if let data = response.data{
                        success(data)
                    }
                    else{
                       failure(kServerErrorData)
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if let  message = response.message {
                        failure(message)
                    }else {
                        failure(kServerError)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                failure(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

My BaseResponse class

```
struct BaseResponse<T:Mappable>:Mappable{
    var status:Int?
    var message:String?
    var data:T?
    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        status  <- map["status"]
        message <- map["message"]
        data    <- map["data"]
    }
    init?(map: Map) {}
}
```

Now usually i am using above method like this

```
 Api.shared.post(obj: TokenResponse.self, endPoint: EndPoints.availability.rawValue, params: [Keys.token:BaseVC.authToken, Keys.availability:NSNumber(value: isAvailable)], success: successBlock)
```

This works fine when response json have keys but now i have to handle this json which dont have keys inside 'data'

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Patient List",

    "data": [
        {
            "user_info": {
                "name": "abx",
                "email": "abx@abx.com.pk",
                "phone": "4087082831"
            },
            "patient_info": {
                "p_name": "abx",
                "p_email": "abx@abx.com.pk",
                "p_phone": "4087082831"
            }
        },
        {

            "user_info": {
                "name": "abx",
                "email": "abx@abx.com.pk",
                "phone": "4087082831"
            },
            "patient_info": {
                "p_name": "abx",
                "p_email": "abx@abx.com.pk",
                "p_phone": "4087082831"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm having trouble creating mappable class for above json since it don't have keys inside data. Please help! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can try:

1. `Api.shared.post(obj: [TokenResponse].self, endPoint: EndPoints.availability.rawValue, params: [Keys.token:BaseVC.authToken, Keys.availability:NSNumber(value: isAvailable)], success: successBlock)`
2. Write another `BaseResponse` class which have `var data:[T]?`

Comment: var data:[T]? this doesnt work either. Because [T] doesnt conforms to mappable.

Comment: I have used [here](https://imgur.com/EY6XDy2) and it conforms with Mappable